# list files with the same first 3 letter followed by a sequence # with shell script

Tags: shell-script

First time to post here.  How do I group files with the same first 3 letters followed by a sequence number in a directory?
e.g.

```
VHS-01-001.avi
VHS-01-002.avi
-------------
VHS-02-001.avi
VHS-02-002.avi
VHS-02-003.avi
---------
Hi8-01-001.avi
Hi8-01-002.avi
Hi8-01-003.avi
```

so that I can pass each group of video files in a function as the following:

```
encode(){
  for avi in "$@" 
  do..
}
```

Comment: do you want to call `encode()` function for each group of files separately?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes I want to process each group of file separately.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not very smart solution:

- sort files by name
- loop through names
- compare characters of last loop:

  ```
  last=""
  ls -1 $1 | sort | while read file; do
      sub=${file:0:3}
      [ "$last" != "$sub" ] && { echo "NEW GROUP"; last="$sub"; }
      echo "[$sub] $file"
  done
  ```

Instead of echo-ing collect filenames inside an array ...

Just an idea ... example output:

```
NEW GROUP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[Hi8] Hi8-01-002.avi                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
NEW GROUP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[VHS] VHS-01-001.avi                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[VHS] VHS-01-002.avi
[VHS] VHS-02-002.avi
NEW GROUP
[XZU] XZU
```

Edit 1:
based on [Anthony Geoghegan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22812/anthony-geoghegan) 's answer avoid the pipes at the beginning of the loop and use bash globbing. Take a look at his comment.

Improved script:

```
last=""
for file in *avi; do
    sub=${file:0:3}
    [ "$last" != "$sub" ] && { echo "NEW GROUP"; last="$sub"; }
    echo "[$sub] $file"
done
```

Edit 2:

as asked by @ [Tony Tan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/115678/tony-tan) in his third comment:
here you find a straigt forward solution to parse the collected file names to a function. There are many ways to do so. And I don't have much experience in bash scripting ... ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="$1"
cd "$SOURCE_DIR" || { echo "could not read dir '$SOURCE_DIR'"; exit 1; }

function parseFiles() {
  echo "parsing files:"
  echo "$1"
}

last=""
declare -a fileGroup

for file in *avi; do
  # first 3 chars of filename
  sub=${file:0:3}

  if test -z "$last"; then
    # last is empty. first loop
    last="$sub"
  elif test "$last" != "$sub"; then
    # new file group detected, parse collected
    parseFiles "${fileGroup[*]}"
    # reset array
    fileGroup=()
    last="$sub"
  fi

  # append name to array
  fileGroup[${#fileGroup[@]}]=$file
done

parseFiles "${fileGroup[*]}"
```

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]. That's a great first post. You can make it even better if you [edit] it to point out that it's applicable to the Bash shell. It's also a [bad idea to parse the output of ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22812): you can actually simplify your first line by replacing it with `for file in *avi; do`.

Comment: Thanks. ;) Maybe we have edited in parallel? I've tried to improve the formatting. Your idea is fine, but the loop will only do it's work if the filenames are sorted. How do you sort `for file in *avi; ...`? On the other hand you use 2 processes less ;)

Comment: When expanding a globbing pattern, POSIX-compliant shells (such as Bash) automatically list the files in alphabetical order (https://superuser.com/a/1117638/247588) ... so you don't actually need the `sort` command. I tried your code with the modified first line and it works fine.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thanks for the globbing pattern hint. I did not know that.

Comment: @ChristophS thanks, the modified codes works

Comment: @ChristophS  I am still new with shell scripting.  What should I do if I need to process each group of files as a whole?  sth like Stephane's code below. I have a working script which will encode a list of video files with certain format depending on their total length and authorize a dvd after encoding. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: @Tony: use the function "parseFiles". The param `$1` contains the file group. Rename the function to "encode" and it's the same as Stephane's code - as far as I can see ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
files=(???-??-*.avi)
for prefix (${(Mu)files#???-??-}) encode $prefix*.avi
```

(or `encode ${(M)files:#$prefix*}`)

The equivalent with the GNU shell (`bash`) and tools would be:

```
while IFS= read -u3 -rd '' prefix; do
  encode "$prefix-"*.avi 3<&-
done 3< <(printf '%s\0' ???-??-*.avi | grep -oz '^...-..-' | sort -zu)
```

Same principle. We get the list of files matching the `???-??-*.avi` pattern in the current directory, extract the part that matches (`(M)`/`grep -o`) `???-??-` (regexp `...-..-`), unique them (`(u)`/`sort -u`), and then loop over that list of prefixes.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more your shell script？I am getting following error: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: @TonyTan, that needs to be interpreted by `bash`, not when run as `sh`. When running as `sh`, `bash` doesn't recognise the `<(...)` process substitution syntax.

Comment: @Chazelas   Is there any reason why it works fine in my arch linux system but not in Ubuntu subsystem under Windows 10? It is trying to use prefix (e.g. Hi8-01- VHS-01- etc as files name) in Ubuntu system. The rest of the codes is wokring fine.

Comment: OK. This works in Ubuntu Bash subsystem under Windows 10.  `printf '%s\0' ???-??-*.avi | grep -oz '^...-..-' | sort -zu | while read a; do
  echo "$a*.avi"
done`